# How do we edit the dates of the General Ledger report?

Tags: gnucash, annual-report

We're using PCLinuxOS, updated with GNUCash also updated.  We're trying to edit the General Ledger but there are very few options - only two tabs:  Display and General.  Is there any way to produce this report between specific dates?

Have a radiant afternoon and please be safe!  :)

Comment: The dates should be in the General tab, aren't they there?

Answer (score 1):

OK, on the basis that this now appears to be a question about the GnuCash **General Journal** (and *not* the General Ledger), I'll have another dip.

I agree with the observation that there doesn't seem to be any way to configure the GnuCash **General Journal Report** to report on a specific date range.  By default, the report seems to include every General Journal entry ever made, and this cannot be changed.  There may be a reason based on accounting principles explaining why GnuCash has been built this way - but I'm not an accountant and I don't know the reason.

However, there is a workaround.

1. Start by selecting *Tools/General Journal* to open up the General Journal register.
2. Filter the register by date by selecting *View/Filter by.../Date/Select Range*.  Choose the desired **Start** and **End** dates.  GnuCash will now display only the date-filtered transactions.  This transaction register does not, however, easily allow the transactions to be printed or exported.
3. If printing is required, ensure that the filtered General Journal register is the "current" tab and select *Reports/Account Report*.  This opens up a new tab with the same (filtered) transactions in a report format.  This report can be printed, exported as HTML or exported as a PDF by any of the usual means.

Comment: Dear Greg - wow.  i really appreciate your feedback.  Believe it or not, i had finally figured out the answer you just provided.  All of this is for our local Spiritual Assembly here in Mexicali.  i just really like the program and it's OpenSource! and Free! and even though we have very few friends so the activities are also few, i figured it would be good to start with GNUCash from a few and learn while we grow.  Have a wonderful week!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to configure the **General Ledger Report** in GnuCash (and not edit the **General Ledger** itself) you start by selecting the *General Ledger* report from the *Assets & Liabilities* group under the *Reports* menu.

This will open the General Ledger Report in a new GnuCash tab, with either no accounts selected to report on, or maybe set according to a previously-saved configuration.

You can now configure your General Ledger Report for this run by clicking on the **Options** button in the icon bar here:
[image: Options Icon]

In my GnuCash installation (Version 4.13) this will open up an *Options* dialogue box with 6 tabs:
[image: Report Options dialogue box]

If your GnuCash is only giving you 2 tabs here and not 6, I cannot explain that based on information currently provided.  In any case, the date period to be covered by the report is controlled by selecting dates on the *General* tab of the *Options* dialogue box.

Comment: Thank you very much, Greg, for your very correct reply.  i should have asked about the other General, the General Ledger.  My lack of knowledge of acct. is really showing.  i need to go online and see if there is a list of Accounts that should be included in each of these Generals as well so we can config. the Rpts.

Comment: Sigh... - General Journal.